# Endpoit da API do histórico de vendas da Hotmart não retorna com todos os registros

Tags: python, api, request

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição na API do histórico de vendas da Hotmart através do endpoint abaixo. Porém, a resposta só me traz 14 registros, que é apenas uma parte do total. Alguém já passou por isso?

curl --location --request GET 'https://sandbox.hotmart.com/payments/api/v1/sales/history' \

```
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer :access_token'
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, bom dia!

Conforme a documentação oficial, basta adicionar o parâmetro: **&max_results=999** na sua query, que vai trazer até 999 resultados por vez. Você pode ajustar para o valor que lhe for mais conveniente.

Exemplo:

```
https://developers.hotmart.com/payments/api/v1/sales/history?transaction_status=COMPLETE&start_date=1659322801000&end_date=1662001199000&product_id=2268672&max_results=999
```

Atenciosamente.

Answer (score -1):

Tipicamente, uma API não vai dar todas as informações de uma vez (você não vai querer baixar gigabytes de dados a cada requisição, e muito menos o fornecedor). Em geral, há um sistema de paginação e pode navegar pelas páginas.

---

A documentação da API (https://developers.hotmart.com/docs/en/v1/sales/sales-history/), menciona isso:

> **page_token** *string*

> The cursor used in pagination. It is a reference to the part you want to access in the list.

> E.g., if you make a request that returns 50 items, but the total number of items is 95. By adding the query param page_token with the value of the next_page_token attribute, you will access the remaining 45. In the next request, by changing the page_token to the value prev_page_token, you will again access the previous 50 items.

---

A resposta da sua requisição pode conter o `next_page_token`:

```
  "page_info": {
    "total_results": 14,
    "next_page_token": "eyJyb3dzIjo1LCJwYWdlIjozfQ==",
    "prev_page_token": "eyJyb3dzIjo1LCJwYWdlIjoxfQ==",
    "results_per_page": 5
  }
```

Basta usar o `next_page_token` para o `page_token`, por exemplo:

```
https://sandbox.hotmart.com/payments/api/v1/sales/history?page_token=eyJyb3dzIjo1LCJwYWdlIjozfQ%3D%3D
```

---

Você também pode usar outros recursos (mencionados na documentação) para aumentar a quantida de itens por páginas.

Comment: Pois é, eu cheguei a conferir esse detalhe que você citou, mas no meu caso só aparecem os 14 registros mesmo:

Comment: "page_info": {
        "total_results": 14,
        "results_per_page": 14


Eu pensei que pudesse estar relacionado com o warning que tem na página https://developers.hotmart.com/docs/pt-BR/v1/sales/sales-history/ que diz: 

"Você precisa adicionar na query os filtros transaction e transaction_status para conseguir consultar todos os status que deseja." 

Mas também já coloquei esses filtros de todo jeito que achei aqui e não deu certo... como sou meio leigo acabo ficando perdido rsrs....